# use a XTS inside name of a Variable in r

Tags: r, xts

I have more than 300 stocks downloaded with getsymbols() and I have the name of this stocks in a vector, for example:

```
USA_STOCKS = c("AAL","AAPL","ADBE","ADI","ADP","ADSK","ALGN",
               "ALXN","AMAT","AMGN","AMZN","ASML","ATVI","AVGO",
               "BIDU","BIIB") # This is just an extract from 300
getSymbols(AAL) # this is just one of the 300 "getsymbols"
```

With that, I have a XTS object called AAL and a vector USA_TOCKS with all the name of the XTS Objets.

I would like to do:

```
AAL = na.omit(AAL)
```

But, instead of use the Object AAL, I want to refer the object using the name inside the vector. Something like this:

```
USA_STOCKS[1] = na.omit(USA_STOCKS[1])
```

Obviusly if i did this, I will change only the name of "AAL" inside the vector. But what I want is to refer the object AAL.

Comment: Hi, I just edit the answer. Is it more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, still a bit unclear, but I think you want to do something like this:

```
library(quantmod)

USA_STOCKS = c("AAL","AAPL","ADBE")

# Put all requested quotes in big list
stocks_usa <- lapply(USA_STOCKS,
                     getSymbols,
                     from = "2018-10-01",
                     to = "2018-11-01",
                     auto.assign = F)

# set the names of the list
names(stocks_usa) <- USA_STOCKS

#reference AAL
head(stocks_usa$AAL)

           AAL.Open AAL.High AAL.Low AAL.Close AAL.Volume AAL.Adjusted
2018-10-01    41.41    41.75   39.60     39.61    7210700     39.50097
2018-10-02    39.60    39.60   38.40     38.50    7625000     38.39403
2018-10-03    38.70    39.26   38.42     38.80    6370300     38.69320
2018-10-04    38.80    39.01   37.48     37.92    5916500     37.81562
2018-10-05    37.93    38.13   36.21     36.44    9127000     36.33969
2018-10-08    36.44    36.85   35.60     35.90    7879300     35.80119

# more referencing
stocks_usa$AAL <- na.omit(stocks_usa$AAL)
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I were looking for but your solution solve my problem! Thanks